# MYSQL: BAD_FIELD_ERROR Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

First time using `MySQL` (this is in a `node/react` app) and am encountering an error trying to insert some values into a table. The specific error message I am getting is:

> Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Here is my table:

```
const table =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
     posts(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
           name VARCHAR(30), 
           email VARCHAR(50), 
           content VARCHAR(500), 
           stamp VARCHAR(40), 
           PRIMARY KEY(id))";
```

and here is the query:

```
 //  Insert post 1
app.get("/addpost1", (req, res) => {
  let post = {
    name: "Joe Blogs",
    email: "jblogs@gmail.com",
    content:
      "Interesting post Phil. It's great to see that a blog really can come alive when the comments update in real-time. The commenting system becomes a conversation platform.",
    stamp: "July 30 2019"
  };
  let sql = "INSERT INTO posts SET ?";
  let query = db.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send("Post 1 added...");
  });
});
```

I am continually running into errors with this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion, if "stamp" is a date you should use some date or datetime and not VARCHAR, it will save you lot of time when you will need to do some query according to a date

Comment: Yes I agree it makes sense to use a string because of where it is rendered eventually though ^_^

Comment: I understand your logic, but you always can format the date after you get it

Answer (score 2):

This is the right syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2])
```

so in your code would be like:

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`name`, `email`, `content`) VALUES ([name:], [email:], [content:])
```

Comment: thanks
would the values portion look like this?
VALUES("Joe Blogs", "jblogs@gmail.com") 
...ect?

Comment: `syntax` not `sintax` (the latter sounds like what you would have to pay at Las Vegas)

Comment: would it not be:
VALUES ([post.name:], [post.email:], [post.content:]) ?

Comment: since I must access them within the object? 
or just do away with the object I guess....

Comment: yeah depends how you set your variable, just change the values to your variable

Comment: so it would look like...
VALUES (["Joe Blogs"], ["jblogs@gmail.com"]) 
?

Comment: yeah it also would work, but to keep it more clean you could parse the values into a variable and than insert the variable in the column VALUES

Comment: so if I have 
let name = "john" 
it would be 
VALUES ([name:]) 
specifically? (with the colon>?)

Comment: what are your variables names?

Comment: example would just be
let email = "example.com"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197284/discussion-between-otavio-barreto-and-tomk).